# И снова подсветка текущего раздела

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть скрипт подсветки раздела - добавляет класс родительскому элементу. Работает даже при передаче в адресной строке GET-параметров и с учётом вложенности каталога. НО! У меня есть каталог `/magazine/male_articles/`, а есть вложенные каталоги, например `/magazine/male_articles/some_category/`. Когда переходишь в категорию, то класс добавляется и текущему разделу, и общему разделу `/magazine/male_articles/`, то бишь этот раздел главный, а остальные - вложенные, и так как он присутствует в адресе каждой вложенной ссылки, то и подсвечивается постоянно. Как можно убрать с него подсветку при выборе подкатегорий?

Сам скрипт:

```
$(function () {
$('.magazine_nav ul li a').each(function () {
var location = window.location.href
var link = this.href
var result = location.match(link);

if(result != null) this.parentNode.className = "active_article";
});
});
```

Comment: @Torawhite, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Torawhite, тебе не могут помочь потому, что ты вопрос неправильно задаёшь.  
Я прочитал, нифига не понял, что нужно, прочитал ещё раз, плюнул и забил, хотя мог бы помочь, ибо я хорошо разбираюсь в JS и CSS.

Правильно заданный вопрос - половина решения!

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать, например, так:

```
    $('.magazine_nav li a').each(function () {
      var location = "http://site.ru/make_url_1/make_sub_url/"; // Вставил для примера в вашем случае это window.location.href
      // var location = "http://site.ru/make_url_1/"; Для проверки верхнего пункта меню
      var locationArray = location.split('/');
      var locationPath = locationArray[locationArray.length-2];
      var link = this.href.split('/');
      var linkPath = link[link.length-1];

      if(linkPath ==  locationPath) this.parentNode.className = "active_article";
  });
```

**UPD.**

Без [примера](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/5ugrw4va/1/) нынче никуда, чтобы проверить работоспособность, можно раскомментировать другую строку с location.

Comment: @Torawhite, исправил ошибку, последний элемент в url массива получался пустой элемент, потому что в конце url стоит "/", поэтому нужно писать `locationArray.length-2`

Comment: @Torawhite, ещё раз поправил, и заодно сделал небольшой пример

Comment: @Torawhite, я наверно что-то пропустил, раз в заголовке вопроса присутствует "И снова...", но может быть как-то попроще:

    $('.magazine_nav ul li a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active_article');

Comment: @Torawhite, значит попробуйте вариант @Deonis, если не заработает, то у вас что-то со стилями, только думаю, вам подойдёт вот так:

     $('.magazine_nav ul li a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active_article');

Comment: @Torawhite, ссылки именно в таком виде? Тогда должно работать так:

// класс для самой ссылки
$('.magazine_nav a[href="' + location + '"]').addClass('active_article');
// класс для родительского LI активной ссылки
$('.magazine_nav a[href="' + location + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active_article');

Comment: @Torawhite, неожиданно, что href со "/" на конце, поэтому вот [мой код][1] для вашего примера, изменил с 1 на 2 в парсинге href списка

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/kbxajov6/1/

Comment: @MasterAlex вариант @Deonis работает, но слетает при появлении get-параметров. При пагинации ссылка получает вид типа http://torawhite.ru/magazine/male_articles/index.php?&start=5

Comment: @TheDoctor Есть 3 раздела site.ru, site.ru/market, site.ru/magazine
Необходимо выделить цветом тот раздел, в котором ты находишься. Только нужно, чтобы подсветка работала со вложенными каталогами, при передаче get-параметров и главная (site.ru) выделялась только при нахождении на ней, а при нахождении в других разделах, она снималась. Если так проще)

Comment: @Torawhite, меня мучает один вопрос - почему вы решили это реализовать на клиенте, а не на сервере?

Comment: @Deonis из-за незнания. Опыта и знаний недостаточно(

Comment: @Torawhite, если честно - не очень :)  
Непонятно одно - любой раздел, который просматривается является текущим, т.е. должен быть выделен.  
Одно понятно: определять подсветку по `location` - это нереальный быдлокод.

Comment: @TheDoctor вроде, самая обычная подсветка раздела. :)  Не знаю, как ещё объяснить. Вы можете на самом сайте посмотреть, там же понятно, что подсвечивать, как пользователю. А как тогда подсвечивать, если не по location?